# Why does Multinomial naive bayes work better than SVM and Logistic Regression on small amount of data

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, svm, logistic

I want to do `aspect-based sentiment classification` on user text reviews for mobile phones. For a mobile, `aspect` could be the camera, battery, processor, screen, memory etc. A text review is first broken into sentences and then the `aspect` for each one of them is determined on the basis of a pre-maintained keyword list. One sentence could fall into more than one aspect category. I have to manually annotate each sentence for positive and negative sentiment. With a small number of sentences(say 100 sentences for positive and negative each) I trained classifier-`Multinomial Naive Bayes`, `Logistic Regression` and `SVM` out of which multinomial have best prediction power. I do not have a testing set right now but I could see the prediction and the probability estimate given by multinomial are more satisfactory than the rest. If anyone could help me to explain this behavior since I am asked by my Director to explain it to him.

Answer (score 2):

Logistic regression and SVM are discriminative models. They model only $p(y|x)$. Naive Bayes is a generative model. It models $p(x, y)$. It is well known that when you have very little data that a generative model can beat a discriminative model. This paper by Andrew Ng has some good comparisons.

https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-discriminativegenerative.pdf